# Flutter Supabase Authentication Issue: Unable to Navigate to Home Page After Google Sign-In

Tags: flutter, google-signin, supabase, flutterflow

I am facing an issue with Flutter Supabase authentication. After successfully signing in with Google, the app does not navigate to the home page. The googleSignIn function is called when the user signs in, and the Google sign-in process works fine, but after returning to the app, it remains on the login page instead of navigating to the home page.

```dart
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/backend/supabase/supabase.dart';
import '/actions/actions.dart' as action_blocks;
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

Future<bool> googleSignIn(BuildContext context) async {
  final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

  const webClientId = "my_secret_id_here";
  
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    serverClientId: webClientId,
  );
  final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;
  final accessToken = googleAuth.accessToken;
  final idToken = googleAuth.idToken;

  if (accessToken == null || idToken == null) {
    return false;
  }

  final response = await supabase.auth.signInWithIdToken(
    provider: Provider.google,
    idToken: idToken,
    accessToken: accessToken,
  );

  if (response.error != null) {
    // Handle authentication error, e.g., show a snackbar
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('Authentication failed: ${response.error!.message}'),
      ),
    );
    return false;
  }

  // Authentication successful, navigate to the home page
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home'); // Replace '/home' with your actual home page route
  return true;
}
```

I suspect that the issue might be related to the navigation logic. I have tried using Navigator.pushReplacementNamed to navigate to the home page after successful authentication, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Any insights into what might be causing this issue and how to handle navigation correctly after Google sign-in would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The response object of `signInWithIdToken()` does not have an `error` property, so the following code is invalid, and does not run.

```
if (response.error != null) {
  // Handle authentication error, e.g., show a snackbar
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text('Authentication failed: ${response.error!.message}'),
    ),
  );
  return false;
}
```

Omit it from your code base, and make it like this

```dart
await supabase.auth.signInWithIdToken(
  provider: Provider.google,
  idToken: idToken,
  accessToken: accessToken,
);

Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
```